# appending entire svg to dom element leads to Exception... "String contains an invalid character" code: "5"

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I'd like to appending an entire svg element to an childless element of the DOM. I tried the d3-style and the common style and both lead me to this error:

```
[Exception... "String contains an invalid character" code: "5" nsresult: "0x80530005 (InvalidCharacterError)" location: "<unknown>"]
```

How do I append it correct?

```
// with d3
var dropTargetsDiv = d3.select(".droptargets").html("");
dropTargetsDiv.append(svgPic);

// without d3
var dropTargetsDiv = window.document.getElementById("canvas").parentNode;
dropTargetsDiv.innerHTML="";
dropTargetsDiv.appendChild(window.document.createElement(svgPic));

//the svg content is taken from a text area...
var svgPic = scope.$parent.export;

//and looks fine
<svg id="canvas"><g id="dashboard-content"><rect id="dropPanel"></rect></g></svg>

// the structure
<div class="droptargets"...
 <svg id="canvas"...
  <g id="dashboard-content...
```

Answer (score 2):

D3's [`.append()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#append) doesn't take the *contents* of the element to be appended. To quote the documentation:

> Appends a new element with the specified name as the last child of each element in the current selection [...] The name may be specified either as a constant string or as a function that returns the DOM element to append.

So to append an SVG element, you should do

```
var svg = dropTargetsDiv.append("svg");
```

and then populate the contents of the node, i.e. add the `g` element and anything else that may be there.

Comment: Thank you Lars, but if I really understood the svg content has to be populated? I'm looking for a possibilty to add/import/replace the old svg with an entire svg.

Comment: In that case you can simply detach the DOM SVG node and reattach in a different place. JQuery offers functions for that, see https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 0):

Insert svg text into your SVG DIV by `dropTargetsDiv.innerHTML=mySVGText`. This will completely replace the previous.

Example Below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body style='font-family:arial'>
<center>
<div style='width:90%;background-color:gainsboro;text-align:justify;padding:10px;border-radius:6px;'>
Replace DIV.innerHTML with new SVG text
</div>
<br />New SVG Source:<br />
<textarea id=svgNewSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:100px'>
<svg id="mySVG2" width="400" height="400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<rect width=150 height=100 x=100 y=100 fill=blue />
</svg>
</textarea>

<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'>
<svg id="mySVG1" width="400" height="400"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<circle r=150 cx=200 cy=200 fill=red />
</svg>
</div>
<center><button onClick=replaceSVG()>Replace SVG</button></center>
<br />SVG Source:<br />
<textarea id=svgSourceValue style='font-size:110%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:100px'>
</textarea>
<br />Javascript:<br />
<textarea id=jsValue style='border-radius:26px;font-size:110%;font-weight:bold;color:midnightblue;padding:16px;background-color:beige;border-width:0px;font-size:100%;font-family:lucida console;width:90%;height:200px'></textarea>
</center>
<script id=myScript>
function replaceSVG()
{
    svgDiv.innerHTML=svgNewSourceValue.value
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
}
</script>
<script>
document.addEventListener("onload",init(),false)
function init()
{
    svgSourceValue.value=svgDiv.innerHTML
    jsValue.value=myScript.text
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```